# Data Types for special characters in Sql server r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatatypes

What is the best data type that supports special characters in sql server?

Comment: What special characters, exactly? (That is, what Unicode ranges?)

Comment: @NathanTuggy like apostrophe and parenthesis.. ()'

Answer (score 0):

The answer rather depends on which characters you have in mind.

If you open the Character Map application and look at character codes there (either in the popup tooltip message or in the status bar), then for characters whose codes are lower than U+007E (which is the code for `~`) it would be enough to use [`char` or `varchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). For your convenience, the characters supported by `char` and `varchar` are highlighted in yellow in the picture below:

[image: Character Map]

If you need to support other characters, you *might* get away with either of those two types. That depends on whether the other characters belong to the code page that is used by your operating system as the default for non-Unicode programs. If you do not know whether that is the case or, in fact, you know for certain that the characters you need to support are outside your system locale, choose [`nchar` or `nvarchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx).

Either way, remember to [specify the maximum length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) for your chosen type.